# How to get a list of object from sql connection query?

Tags: c#, mysql, list, select, database-connection

I have sql query written in c#.(DataType class has str_name and int_something). Code is like the following

```
List<DataType> allDataType=SQLConnection.Query<DataType>("select str_name,int_something from sqlite_master where type = ?", type_name);
```

I already got parameterless constructor inside DataType, but still I got a list of object that hasn't been initialized. str_name is empty string while int_something is always 0. But I can get the correct number of rows of data. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

What actually `SQLConnection.Query<T>(string s)` is? `SQLConnection` doesn't have such a method, so I assume it's an extension method that you have defined in your project. The problem is that method. Try searching a bug in the implementation of that method.

Comment: Yes, it is some method that my project has, I removed some information for confidential purpose, sorry for that...

Comment: Then find the problem in that method. The problem is obviously there.

Comment: I found something interesting, that is when I tried to get the data from normal table it works, when I try to get data from sqlite_master, it will not work properly. It can get correct rows of data but cannot initialize the object. Do you know if there is anything to do with sqlite_master?

Comment: I don't think the problem is the table. I think the problem is the way you have implemented your method. Have you tried to debug it and see values at 'watch' window? I can't help much if I don't see the code where the problem actually is.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you looking for I gather

```
public List<NumberPattern> GetNumberPattern(int number)
        {
            using var cnn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Server.ConnectionString);
            var resp = cnn.Query<NumberPattern>($"exec GetNumberPatternRows {number};");
            if (resp != null)
            {
                return resp.ToList();
            }
            return null;
        }
```